# Using a Lucene ShingleFilter to extract frequencies of bigrams in Lucene

Tags: lucene, filtering, n-gram

If a Lucene ShingleFilter can be used to tokenize a string into shingles, or ngrams, of different sizes, e.g.:

```
"please divide this sentence into shingles"
```

Becomes:

```
shingles "please divide", "divide this", "this sentence", "sentence into", and "into shingles"
```

Does anyone know if this can be used in conjunction with other analyzers to return the frequencies of the bigrams or trigrams found, e.g.:

```
"please divide this please divide sentence into shingles"
```

Would return 2 for "please divide"?

I should add that my strings are built up from a database and then indexed by Lucene in memory and are not persisted. Use of other products like Solr is not intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing my snowballAnalyzer and standardAnalyzers as parameters to ShingleFilterWrappers and processing the outputs via a TermVectorMapper.